# Why my OpenGL sphere looks like a ellipse

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I created one sphere using OpenGL ES20 in Android. In a perspective projection env, I animate the sphere from [-1.5, -2, -2] to [-1.5, 2, -2] . The problem is that, the sphere looks like a ellipse when it reach the frustum boundary. Indeed, it only look like a circle when it is at [0, 0, -2], the more it away from the [0,0], the more it looks like a ellipse.

Is this the standard behavior ? I thought, one sphere should look like a circle in all angles of view.  Could you please help ?

[image: The sphere]

Answer (score 1):

You should lessen your field of view; what you show is normal and is a side effect of the slightly artificial nature of a 3d projection — a 3d projection assumes the viewer is sitting a fixed distance from the screen and that their eyes are positioned along z directly from the centre of the screen looking exactly forwards. Check out the related problems [described here](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/lihi/Demos/SquarePanorama.html) for a description of the same effect with a real camera.

Quite often the implicit default field of view is ninety degrees. But when you hold a phone in your hand it occupies much less than ninety degrees of your vision.

If you're using `glFrustum` then try specifying lesser values for left, right, top and bottom. As a quick fix, just throw a `glScalef` by, say, 2.0 onto your projection stack (or your ES 2 equivalent) after computing your projection matrix.